# Unable to store special character on Google Cloud SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have two MySQL instances: locally and on Google Cloud SQL. The same database is created on both with charset `utf8mb4`, which can be verified when I run:

```
show variables like "character_set_database";
```

Also for both Databases, I import data from the same `csv` file.

One of the text columns has special characters like this: `⌛ ABC`. When my webpage retrieves from the local instance, it can display fine, but when I switch to retrieve data from the Google Cloud instance, I got `?⌛? ABC`. How do I fix that?

Comment: does [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/enable-full-unicode-in-mysql-on-google-cloud-aaa2635486d6) solves your issue?

Comment: @Chris32 yes, it's solved now! If you can put in an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/enable-full-unicode-in-mysql-on-google-cloud-aaa2635486d6) In order to convert a DB encoding, you will need to write ALTER commands on the database.

This SQL script can be useful for this

```
# Convert the DB first
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> 
CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# Convert each table
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# Convert each column
# All varchar columns should be converted to stay consistent
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
  CHANGE <varchar_col1> <varchar_col1> VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  CHANGE <varchar_col2> <varchar_col2> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# Repair each table
REPAIR TABLE <table_name>
# Optimize each table
OPTIMIZE TABLE <table_name>
```

After this update the `character_set_server` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) in your Cloud SQL instance to `utf8mb4`

Now restart your Cloud SQL Instance and that's all

Please make a backup of your data before making any changes!